# What could cause a digital circuit breaker finder to not find a breaker?

Tags: electrical

I just purchased a Klein ET300 Digital Circuit Breaker finder. I tested it with known circuits so I can figure out how it works.

One room in my house that I have always had problems with is not showing any corresponding breakers to the outlets. Almost as if it had no breaker. The room was once two rooms many years ago which was merged into one room. The house was built in 1966 so some of the electric does not have "ground" connections. This house was an electrical nightmare when I purchased it. I repaired much of it myself to correct things such as "over 15 outlets/fixtures on one breaker" and "heavy loads on one line" to resolve these issues I have had to run completely new lines and reduced the loads on the original lines.

What could be the problem with this room? or Line?

Comment: Have you checked for auxiliary panels? Is there a master breaker and does that cut off power to the outlet? Have you tried plugging in a radio, playing it loud and switching each breaker off one by one?

Comment: Its possible the outlet has been accidentally wired to two circuit breakers on the same phase.  This is unsafe.  If there is no single breaker that turns it off, see if there is some combination of breakers that do turn it off.

Comment: I found the breaker that shuts it off. but it's always been a weird line. it would not respond to the ET300. my concern is the neutral/ground is an issue. like i said this house has some screwed up electrical work. and I'm not about tearing up all the electric without first knowing what could be wrong. no auxiliary panels unless their hidden in some crawl space, but the box doesn't show any heavy gauge lines reflecting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not help you with that particular tool.  But a word of advice.  Sometimes I have to put down my induction testor, or magnetic resonance testor and grab the radio.
plug in radio to outlet in that room and turn on high.  Turn off all breakers.
turn them back on one at a time, listen.  Do not stop if you hear the radio. Go through all the breakers.
You may have two circuits feeding that room.

Tools are nice but sometimes there is no substitute for direct observation.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. in this house most rooms have more than one breaker feeding it. Shoot! i even have 4 breakers on one wall two of which are in one double receptacle box. and all these wires are less than 6 inches from their outlets.